# RelativeLayout wrap_content problem

Tags: android

I want to display 3 images on a background image. First I thought of using a relative layout and setting the background to be my background image. Then I placed the images in the layout: left, center and right. The problem is that the relative layout fills the whole screen and the background image is scaled. Using the background image as an image view in the layout is not an option, because I want my 3 images to have a maximum height determined by the background height. What is the best way to achieve this? here is my code too:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:background="@drawable/instruction_background">
<ImageView android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>   
<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/background"
    android:src="@drawable/apple_sauce"/>
<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:src="@drawable/white_wine"/>
<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:src="@drawable/tuna_fish"/>
```

Best Regards

Comment: So you want the height of your background image determine the hight of what exactly? I'm not really getting it.

Comment: I want the background image height to determine the layout's height. And a foreground image should be down scaled automatically, if it's height is larger than the background image height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your 3 foreground images are arranged linearly, so put them in a horizontal `LinearLayout`. Then let the ImageView hold the background image, and set your LinearLayout to align with the ImageView's edges. The size of the ImageView will be determined by the image content.

i.e.:

```
<RelativeLayout>

  <ImageView android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/instruction_background"
   /> 

  <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:alignLeft="@id/background"
    android:alignTop="@id/background"
    android:alignRight="@id/background"
    android:alignBottom="@id/background"
  >

    <ImageView ... />
    <ImageView ... />
    <ImageView ... />
  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The foreground images are arranged linearly, but a linear layout isn't good for me, because I want to keep the images sizes, and I want to have overlapped image views when is needed for a more realistic effect.

Comment: Your question says the foreground images are "left, center and right." Sounds linear to me. Use a <RelativeLayout> instead then. Has your original problem been solved?